# Using a different redis connection to process jobs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-queue

I have a system where I spin up, every hour, tons of jobs and I would like them to be handled on a different redis connection, separate from the main one jobs are popped on to so they do not interfere with other jobs (ie, delaying them) that get pushed on to the queue.

So I did the following, I created a new redis connection:

```
    'kingdom_jobs' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 2),
    ],
```

Then created a new Queue Connection:

```
    'kingdom_jobs' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'kingdom_jobs', // Uses the new connection
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],
```

Then in the loop that spins up all these jobs:

```
    Kingdom::chunkById(250, function($kingdoms) use ($service) {
        foreach ($kingdoms as $kingdom) {
            UpdateKingdomJob::dispatch($kingdom)->onConnection('kingdom_jobs');
        }
    });
```

The issue?

Ya they get pushed to this new connection, I see them in horizon - over 500 of them - but they don't do anything. They don't get processed. Is there a way to tell horizon to process this additional connection?

I currently use `php artisan horizon` in development to process jobs - is there another step?

I assume from the docs, there is some step I am missing, I assume it has to do with `php artisan queue:work --tries = 3` from the docs? Trying that did nothing. Do I need another instance of horizon for this new connection or do I configure horizon to know about this connection?

**Help?**

Comment: I don't mean to drag open an old thread but what version of laravel are you on? I'm having issues getting horizon to actually process the jobs on the separate queue. I've got the supervisor configuration set up appropriately, set up the separate queue, but I'm not able to run the queued jobs that aren't on the default connection. I can run it manually with `php artisan queue:work --queue=my-queue` but `artisan horizon` just doesn't seem pick up the jobs for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you don't have a Horizon supervisor setup to watch your new queue.

Looking at the Horizon config:

```
'environments' => [
    'production' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'minProcesses' => 1,
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
            'tries' => 3,
        ],
    ],
],
```

It looks like we can just add another supervisor to the production environment (and others if you need it):

```
'environments' => [
    'production' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'minProcesses' => 1,
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
            'tries' => 3,
        ],
        'supervisor-2' => [
            'connection' => 'kingdom_jobs',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'minProcesses' => 1,
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
            'tries' => 3,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: I was just about to delete my question as I figured it out hahahaha, thank for this though :D

Comment: Sometimes the act of asking a question gets the wheels turning and you stumble upon the answer! Hopefully it helps someone else in the future.